# Regex to exclude file pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regex which I want to ignore sass partials:

At the moment it looks like this:

```
  match /app\/stylesheets\/(?:.+\/)?[^_].+\.s[ca]ss/ do
    sass
  end
```

Example file paths I want to parse are:

```
/app/stylesheets/nonpartial.scss
/app/stylesheets/folder/anothernonpartial.scss
```

And examples of the partials I want to ignore are

```
/app/stylesheets/_partial.scss                   #this is ignored
/app/stylesheets/partials/_anotherpartial.scss   #this gets a match
```

The partials are not getting picked up by the regex, can anyone suggest a better one?

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want to ignore sass partials but you want to pick up the partials? would you please post a sample of what should be matched and what shouldn't?

Comment: Sorry, I hope that is better.  Basically I want to ignore everything with file that begins with an underscore that resides in the stylesheets folder or any subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/app\/stylesheets(\/(\w+?))*\/(?!_)(\w+?)\.s[ca]ss/
```

This RegEx will match a file in /app/stylesheets in an arbitrary number of subdiretories whereas the filename must not begin with an underscore.

This RegEx uses [Look-Arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).